# how to configure bazel toolchain for cross compile use rules_foreign_cc

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, bazel, arm64

my project need cross compile for arm aarch64 on ubuntu x86_64, but failed at configure stage, below is log

### log

```
# Execution platform: //platforms:linux_gcc9_aarch64
SUBCOMMAND: # @boost//:filesystem [action 'Linking external/boost/libfilesystem.so', configuration: fc89852de14da3c51e8226c7c5e3087929e4f56710d05ed9ab86ed21b8eb16d4, execution platform: //platforms:linux_gcc9_aarch64]
(cd /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/root/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/root/src/go/bin:/usr/local/jdk-11.0.15/bin:/root/.ft:/data/.cache/npm/global/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -shared -o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/libfilesystem.so bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/_objs/filesystem/codecvt_error_category.o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/_objs/filesystem/directory.o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/_objs/filesystem/exception.o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/_objs/filesystem/operations.o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/_objs/filesystem/path.o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/_objs/filesystem/path_traits.o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/_objs/filesystem/portability.o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/_objs/filesystem/unique_path.o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/_objs/filesystem/utf8_codecvt_facet.o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boost/_objs/filesystem/windows_file_codecvt.o -Wl,-S -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-no-as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wall -pass-exit-codes '-fuse-ld=gold')
# Configuration: fc89852de14da3c51e8226c7c5e3087929e4f56710d05ed9ab86ed21b8eb16d4
# Execution platform: //platforms:linux_gcc9_aarch64
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/BUILD.bazel:130:10: BootstrapGNUMake external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make failed: (Exit 1): bash failed: error executing command
  (cd /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/root/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/root/src/go/bin:/usr/local/jdk-11.0.15/bin:/root/.ft:/data/.cache/npm/global/bin \
  /bin/bash -c bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-277332AD/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make_tool_foreign_cc/wrapper_build_script.sh)
# Configuration: 920514b75167e08aaf5b08b6fc5ff1721a7e3be841d2c442cd3624a15e568e52
# Execution platform: //platforms:linux_gcc9_aarch64
rules_foreign_cc: Build failed!
rules_foreign_cc: Keeping temp build directory and dependencies directory for debug.
rules_foreign_cc: Please note that the directories inside a sandbox are still cleaned unless you specify --sandbox_debug Bazel command line flag.
rules_foreign_cc: Printing build logs:
_____ BEGIN BUILD LOGS _____
+ AR=/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
+ ARFLAGS=rcsD
+ CC=/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc
+ CFLAGS='-fPIC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -g0 -O3 -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funsafe-math-optimizations -ftree-vectorize -std=c99 -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__=redacted -D__TIMESTAMP__=redacted -D__TIME__=redacted'
+ LD=/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc
+ LDFLAGS='-lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-no-as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wall -pass-exit-codes -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--gc-sections'
+ ./configure --without-guile --with-guile=no --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-277332AD/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-277332AD/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make.build_tmpdir':
```

config.log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by gperftools configure 2.9.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/com_github_gperftools_gperftools/configure --prefix=/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_gperftools_gperftools/gperftools_build.build_tmpdir/gperftools_build --enable-shared=no --enable-frame-pointers --disable-libunwind

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = ubuntu
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.4.0-109-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 09:10:54 UTC 2022

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_gperftools_gperftools/gperftools_build.ext_build_deps/bin
PATH: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo
PATH: /root/.cargo/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin
PATH: /usr/local/go/bin
PATH: /root/src/go/bin
PATH: /usr/local/jdk-11.0.15/bin
PATH: /root/.ft
PATH: /data/.cache/npm/global/bin
PATH: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_gperftools_gperftools/gperftools_build.ext_build_deps/bin/toolchains


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2617: checking build system type
configure:2631: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2651: checking host system type
configure:2664: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2700: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2768: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2779: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2834: result: yes
configure:2978: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3017: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:3024: checking for gawk
configure:3040: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:3051: result: gawk
configure:3062: checking whether /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make/bin/make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3084: result: yes
configure:3113: checking whether /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make/bin/make supports nested variables
configure:3130: result: yes
configure:3260: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3269: result: no
configure:3296: checking for git
configure:3314: found /usr/local/bin/git
configure:3327: result: /usr/local/bin/git
configure:3400: checking whether /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make/bin/make supports the include directive
configure:3415: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make/bin/make -f confmf.GNU && cat confinc.out
this is the am__doit target
configure:3418: $? = 0
configure:3437: result: yes (GNU style)
configure:3507: checking for gcc
configure:3534: result: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc
configure:3763: checking for C compiler version
configure:3772: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc --version >&5
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10)) 9.2.1 20191025
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3783: $? = 0
configure:3772: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-none-linux-gnu
Configured with: /tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/src/gcc/configure --target=aarch64-none-linux-gnu --prefix= --with-sysroot=/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/libc --with-build-sysroot=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/build-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/install//aarch64-none-linux-gnu/libc --with-bugurl=https://bugs.linaro.org/ --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-shared --disable-libssp --disable-libmudflap --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-gmp=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/build-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/host-tools --with-mpfr=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/build-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/host-tools --with-mpc=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/build-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/host-tools --with-isl=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/build-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/host-tools --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --with-pkgversion='GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10)'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.1 20191025 (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10)) 
configure:3783: $? = 0
configure:3772: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -V >&5
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3783: $? = 1
configure:3772: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -qversion >&5
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3783: $? = 1
configure:3803: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3825: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -fPIC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c99 -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__=redacted -D__TIMESTAMP__=redacted -D__TIME__=redacted  -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-no-as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wall -pass-exit-codes -fuse-ld=gold -lpthread conftest.c  >&5
configure:3829: $? = 0
configure:3877: result: yes
configure:3880: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3882: result: a.out
configure:3888: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3895: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -o conftest -fPIC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c99 -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__=redacted -D__TIMESTAMP__=redacted -D__TIME__=redacted  -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-no-as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wall -pass-exit-codes -fuse-ld=gold -lpthread conftest.c  >&5
configure:3899: $? = 0
configure:3921: result: 
configure:3943: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3951: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/gcc9_arm_aarch64/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -o conftest -fPIC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c99 -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__=redacted -D__TIMESTAMP__=redacted -D__TIME__=redacted  -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-no-as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wall -pass-exit-codes -fuse-ld=gold -lpthread conftest.c  >&5
configure:3955: $? = 0
configure:3962: ./conftest
/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/external/com_github_gperftools_gperftools/configure: line 3964: ./conftest: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
configure:3966: $? = 126
configure:3973: error: in `/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/dbf178c3b436e7b271af34e78939cab5/execroot/bazel_simple_demo/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_gperftools_gperftools/gperftools_build.build_tmpdir':
configure:3975: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

### bazel toolchain configuration:

toolchain:

```
http_archive(
    name = "gcc9_arm_aarch64",
    build_file = "@bazel_build_file_repo//bazel:gcc_arm_aarch64.BUILD",
    sha256 = "8dfe681531f0bd04fb9c53cf3c0a3368c616aa85d48938eebe2b516376e06a66",
    strip_prefix = "gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu",
    #urls = ["https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/9.2-2019.12/binrel/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz"],
    urls = ["file:///root/src/cpp/toolchains/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz"],
)
```

platform config

```
constraint_setting(name = "gcc_version")

constraint_value(
    name = "gcc_9",
    constraint_setting = ":gcc_version",
)

constraint_value(
    name = "gcc_10",
    constraint_setting = ":gcc_version",
)

constraint_value(
    name = "gcc_11",
    constraint_setting = ":gcc_version",
)

platform(
    name = "linux_gcc9_aarch64",
    constraint_values = [
        "@platforms//cpu:aarch64",
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        ":gcc_9",
    ],
)
```

toolchain config

```
toolchain(
    name = "gcc9_arm_aarch64_xcompile_toolchain",
    exec_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
        "@platforms//os:linux",
    ],
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//cpu:aarch64",
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "//platforms:gcc_9",
    ],
    toolchain = "@gcc9_arm_aarch64//:cc_toolchain",
    toolchain_type = "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type",
)
```

here is a very tiny demo to reproduce it:
[enter link description here][https://github.com/xiedeacc/bazel_simple_demo.git]